# Mat select click outside not working, when drop down close

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-material-5

I have drop down made with Mat select angular component, I need to trigger an event when I clicked outside of the drop down (body of the page).

```
<mat-select #select multiple (change)="onSubmit($event)" [(ngModel)]="emp">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let value of filter.default" [value]="value">
        {{value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Here is my ts file

```
export class AnotherComponent {
  public text: String;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("clicked inside");
    } else {
      console.log("clicked outside");
    }
  }

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {

  }
}
```

Its not working properly, please help

Comment: what do u mean not working properly?

Comment: if I click on open drop down options, its also showing "clicked outside" in console, it should display only if drop down close, please advise

Comment: use  if(!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target))

Comment: If I click to open the drop down it also shows "clicked outside" in console.

Comment: Any way to exclude particular element

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to know when the select panel is closed, use the `openedChange` event:

```
<mat-select #select multiple (change)="onSubmit($event)" [(ngModel)]="emp"
    (openedChange)="openedChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let value of filter.default" [value]="value">
        {{value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>


openedChange(opened: boolean) {
    console.log(opened ? 'opened' : 'closed');
}
```