# mat-select in Angular Material - is there a way to intercept the closing of the select event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using  with multi selection property. I would like to have an event that gets fired when the user closes the panel, e.g. by clicking outside the panel. Is there a way to get hold of such an event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mat select click outside not working, when drop down close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698658/mat-select-click-outside-not-working-when-drop-down-close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question - [Mat select click outside not working, when drop down close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698658/mat-select-click-outside-not-working-when-drop-down-close)

You can use the openedChange event: `(openedChange)="openedChange($event)"`

[mat-select api](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) - `@Output() openedChange: EventEmitter<boolean>` - Event emitted when the select panel has been toggled.